# What's the difference between Kubernetes-native and non-native applications?

Tags: kubernetes

From the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/):

> For Kubernetes-native applications, Kubernetes offers a simple Endpoints API that is updated whenever the set of Pods in a Service changes. For non-native applications, Kubernetes offers a virtual-IP-based bridge to Services which redirects to the backend Pods.

What is the exact difference between Kubernetes-native and non-native applications?

Answer (score 4):

I found the same section and interpret it as :

- native are apps that are packed up and run inside k8s as some ‚kind‘. All dockerized apps should be in that category.
- non native is connected with the k8s cluster infrastructure but not deployed within. A legacy app, an Oracle cluster or your backup robot may fall in this category.

Comment: Maybe. I interpret that as running binaries vs containers in K8s but we're guessing.

Answer (score 0):

From my interpretation, non-native applications are [Services-without-selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors), for which end-point are not created,(such as application running in different namespace, running outside kubernetes, development databases etc.)